# My coffee pot is a 12 cup Cooks.It has a built in filter yet i still feel the need to put a regular filter in it as well.Am i just being foolish?

Tags: filter, paper-filter

1. Cook 12 Cup Pot
2. Self filtration installed
3. Use of regular filters as well

Comment: "*Am i just being foolish?*" That depends on why you feel this need.

Comment: It might be better to focus the question on the benefits or disadvantages of adding a paper filter on top of a metal filter. Right now, the question seems to be primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

Totally up to you.

A paper filter will filter the oils in the coffee and give you a "brighter" flavor in your coffee. Filtering the oil out may also change the health factors of drinking coffee, since those oils provide nutrition elements that are both good for you and bad for you.

The metal filter by itself will let oils and fines into your final brew. The oils will make the coffee taste richer and more earthy. The fines (which are dust like fine grinds of coffee) will create some sludge in the final brew. Not a lot probably, but some.

I suggest that if you like how the coffee tastes with a paper filter, keep using a paper filter. And if you want to try without paper, consult the manual first to make absolutely sure this is ok with your machine. I can't tell which model Cooks 12 cup you have, so I don't know if your machine actually has a permanent filter or just a basket.